# 802.11X family security protocol identification stage

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

In what stage (Probing?) in the connection process does the AP "tells" the host it's security protocol? (e.g. "I'm using WEP,WPA etc.)
I've sniffed a packet using wireshark but I can't find any security information in it(probing packet), furthermore, I've guessed that during the association request I should've seen the password itself (Hashed) somewhere, no?

```
Frame 1087: 243 bytes on wire (1944 bits), 243 bytes captured (1944 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (\\.\airpcap00)
    Encapsulation type: IEEE 802.11 plus radiotap radio header (23)
    Arrival Time: Mar 18, 2014 21:32:34.530912000 Jerusalem Standard Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1395171154.530912000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.002115000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.052362000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 16.649345000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1087
    Frame Length: 243 bytes (1944 bits)
    Capture Length: 243 bytes (1944 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: radiotap:wlan_radio:wlan]
Radiotap Header v0, Length 20
    Header revision: 0
    Header pad: 0
    Header length: 20
    Present flags
        Present flags word: 0x000018ee
    Flags: 0x10
        .... ...0 = CFP: False
        .... ..0. = Preamble: Long
        .... .0.. = WEP: False
        .... 0... = Fragmentation: False
        ...1 .... = FCS at end: True
        ..0. .... = Data Pad: False
        .0.. .... = Bad FCS: False
        0... .... = Short GI: False
    Data Rate: 1.0 Mb/s
    Channel frequency: 2412 [BG 1]
    Channel flags: 0x00a0, Complementary Code Keying (CCK), 2 GHz spectrum
    Antenna signal: -71dBm
    Antenna noise: -100dBm
    Signal Quality: 76
    Antenna: 0
    dB antenna signal: 29dB
802.11 radio information
    PHY type: 802.11b (4)
    Short preamble: False
    Data rate: 1.0 Mb/s
    Channel: 1
    Frequency: 2412MHz
    Signal strength (dBm): -71dBm
    Noise level (dBm): -100dBm
    [Duration: 1976µs]
IEEE 802.11 Probe Response, Flags: ........C
    Type/Subtype: Probe Response (0x0005)
    Frame Control Field: 0x5000
        .... ..00 = Version: 0
        .... 00.. = Type: Management frame (0)
        0101 .... = Subtype: 5
        Flags: 0x00
    .000 0001 0011 1010 = Duration: 314 microseconds
    Receiver address: Apple_b5:b8:13 (bc:3b:af:b5:b8:13)
    Destination address: Apple_b5:b8:13 (bc:3b:af:b5:b8:13)
    Transmitter address: Sagemcom_fb:5d:9d (00:78:9e:fb:5d:9d)
    Source address: Sagemcom_fb:5d:9d (00:78:9e:fb:5d:9d)
    BSS Id: Sagemcom_fb:5d:9d (00:78:9e:fb:5d:9d)
    .... .... .... 0000 = Fragment number: 0
    0011 0011 0000 .... = Sequence number: 816
    Frame check sequence: 0xd381a870 [correct]
    [FCS Status: Good]
IEEE 802.11 wireless LAN
    Fixed parameters (12 bytes)
        Timestamp: 0x0000008df3014db9
        Beacon Interval: 0.102400 [Seconds]
        Capabilities Information: 0x0411
            .... .... .... ...1 = ESS capabilities: Transmitter is an AP
            .... .... .... ..0. = IBSS status: Transmitter belongs to a BSS
            .... ..0. .... 00.. = CFP participation capabilities: No point coordinator at AP (0x00)
            .... .... ...1 .... = Privacy: AP/STA can support WEP
            .... .... ..0. .... = Short Preamble: Not Allowed
            .... .... .0.. .... = PBCC: Not Allowed
            .... .... 0... .... = Channel Agility: Not in use
            .... ...0 .... .... = Spectrum Management: Not Implemented
            .... .1.. .... .... = Short Slot Time: In use
            .... 0... .... .... = Automatic Power Save Delivery: Not Implemented
            ...0 .... .... .... = Radio Measurement: Not Implemented
            ..0. .... .... .... = DSSS-OFDM: Not Allowed
            .0.. .... .... .... = Delayed Block Ack: Not Implemented
            0... .... .... .... = Immediate Block Ack: Not Implemented
    Tagged parameters (183 bytes)
        Tag: SSID parameter set: HOTBOX-9810
            Tag Number: SSID parameter set (0)
            Tag length: 11
            SSID: HOTBOX-9810
        Tag: Supported Rates 1(B), 2(B), 5.5(B), 11(B), 18, 24, 36, 54, [Mbit/sec]
            Tag Number: Supported Rates (1)
            Tag length: 8
            Supported Rates: 1(B) (0x82)
            Supported Rates: 2(B) (0x84)
            Supported Rates: 5.5(B) (0x8b)
            Supported Rates: 11(B) (0x96)
            Supported Rates: 18 (0x24)
            Supported Rates: 24 (0x30)
            Supported Rates: 36 (0x48)
            Supported Rates: 54 (0x6c)
        Tag: DS Parameter set: Current Channel: 1
            Tag Number: DS Parameter set (3)
            Tag length: 1
            Current Channel: 1
        Tag: ERP Information
            Tag Number: ERP Information (42)
            Tag length: 1
            ERP Information: 0x00
        Tag: ERP Information
            Tag Number: ERP Information (47)
            Tag length: 1
            ERP Information: 0x00
        Tag: RSN Information
            Tag Number: RSN Information (48)
            Tag length: 24
            RSN Version: 1
            Group Cipher Suite: 00:0f:ac (Ieee 802.11) TKIP
            Pairwise Cipher Suite Count: 2
            Pairwise Cipher Suite List 00:0f:ac (Ieee 802.11) AES (CCM) 00:0f:ac (Ieee 802.11) TKIP
            Auth Key Management (AKM) Suite Count: 1
            Auth Key Management (AKM) List 00:0f:ac (Ieee 802.11) PSK
            RSN Capabilities: 0x000c
        Tag: Extended Supported Rates 6, 9, 12, 48, [Mbit/sec]
            Tag Number: Extended Supported Rates (50)
            Tag length: 4
            Extended Supported Rates: 6 (0x0c)
            Extended Supported Rates: 9 (0x12)
            Extended Supported Rates: 12 (0x18)
            Extended Supported Rates: 48 (0x60)
        Tag: HT Capabilities (802.11n D1.10)
            Tag Number: HT Capabilities (802.11n D1.10) (45)
            Tag length: 26
            HT Capabilities Info: 0x18fc
                .... .... .... ...0 = HT LDPC coding capability: Transmitter does not support receiving LDPC coded packets
                .... .... .... ..0. = HT Support channel width: Transmitter only supports 20MHz operation
                .... .... .... 11.. = HT SM Power Save: SM Power Save disabled (0x3)
                .... .... ...1 .... = HT Green Field: Transmitter is able to receive PPDUs with Green Field (GF) preamble
                .... .... ..1. .... = HT Short GI for 20MHz: Supported
                .... .... .1.. .... = HT Short GI for 40MHz: Supported
                .... .... 1... .... = HT Tx STBC: Supported
                .... ..00 .... .... = HT Rx STBC: No Rx STBC support (0x0)
                .... .0.. .... .... = HT Delayed Block ACK: Transmitter does not support HT-Delayed BlockAck
                .... 1... .... .... = HT Max A-MSDU length: 7935 bytes
                ...1 .... .... .... = HT DSSS/CCK mode in 40MHz: Will/Can use DSSS/CCK in 40 MHz
                ..0. .... .... .... = HT PSMP Support: Won't/Can't support PSMP operation
                .0.. .... .... .... = HT Forty MHz Intolerant: Use of 40 MHz transmissions unrestricted/allowed
                0... .... .... .... = HT L-SIG TXOP Protection support: Not supported
            A-MPDU Parameters: 0x1b
            Rx Supported Modulation and Coding Scheme Set: MCS Set
            HT Extended Capabilities: 0x0000
            Transmit Beam Forming (TxBF) Capabilities: 0x00000000
            Antenna Selection (ASEL) Capabilities: 0x00
        Tag: HT Information (802.11n D1.10)
            Tag Number: HT Information (802.11n D1.10) (61)
            Tag length: 22
            Primary Channel: 1
            HT Information Subset (1 of 3): 0x08
            HT Information Subset (2 of 3): 0x0004
            HT Information Subset (3 of 3): 0x0000
            Rx Supported Modulation and Coding Scheme Set: Basic MCS Set
        Tag: Vendor Specific: Broadcom
            Tag Number: Vendor Specific (221)
            Tag length: 9
            OUI: 00:10:18 (Broadcom)
            Vendor Specific OUI Type: 2
            Vendor Specific Data: 0202f02c0000
        Tag: Vendor Specific: Microsoft Corp.: WPA Information Element
            Tag Number: Vendor Specific (221)
            Tag length: 28
            OUI: 00:50:f2 (Microsoft Corp.)
            Vendor Specific OUI Type: 1
            Type: WPA Information Element (0x01)
            WPA Version: 1
            Multicast Cipher Suite: 00:50:f2 (Microsoft Corp.) TKIP
            Unicast Cipher Suite Count: 2
            Unicast Cipher Suite List 00:50:f2 (Microsoft Corp.) AES (CCM) 00:50:f2 (Microsoft Corp.) TKIP
            Auth Key Management (AKM) Suite Count: 1
            Auth Key Management (AKM) List 00:50:f2 (Microsoft Corp.) PSK
        Tag: Vendor Specific: Microsoft Corp.: WMM/WME: Parameter Element
            Tag Number: Vendor Specific (221)
            Tag length: 24
            OUI: 00:50:f2 (Microsoft Corp.)
            Vendor Specific OUI Type: 2
            Type: WMM/WME (0x02)
            WME Subtype: Parameter Element (1)
            WME Version: 1
            WME QoS Info: 0x80
            Reserved: 00
            Ac Parameters ACI 0 (Best Effort), ACM no, AIFSN 3, ECWmin/max 4/10 (CWmin/max 15/1023), TXOP 0
            Ac Parameters ACI 1 (Background), ACM no, AIFSN 7, ECWmin/max 4/10 (CWmin/max 15/1023), TXOP 0
            Ac Parameters ACI 2 (Video), ACM no, AIFSN 2, ECWmin/max 3/4 (CWmin/max 7/15), TXOP 94
            Ac Parameters ACI 3 (Voice), ACM no, AIFSN 2, ECWmin/max 2/3 (CWmin/max 3/7), TXOP 47
```

And here is the association request:

```
Frame 731: 210 bytes on wire (1680 bits), 210 bytes captured (1680 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (\\.\airpcap00)
    Encapsulation type: IEEE 802.11 plus radiotap radio header (23)
    Arrival Time: Mar 18, 2014 21:32:33.235805000 Jerusalem Standard Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1395171153.235805000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001751000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 3.447067000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 15.354238000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 731
    Frame Length: 210 bytes (1680 bits)
    Capture Length: 210 bytes (1680 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: radiotap:wlan_radio:wlan]
Radiotap Header v0, Length 20
    Header revision: 0
    Header pad: 0
    Header length: 20
    Present flags
        Present flags word: 0x000018ee
    Flags: 0x10
        .... ...0 = CFP: False
        .... ..0. = Preamble: Long
        .... .0.. = WEP: False
        .... 0... = Fragmentation: False
        ...1 .... = FCS at end: True
        ..0. .... = Data Pad: False
        .0.. .... = Bad FCS: False
        0... .... = Short GI: False
    Data Rate: 1.0 Mb/s
    Channel frequency: 2412 [BG 1]
    Channel flags: 0x00a0, Complementary Code Keying (CCK), 2 GHz spectrum
    Antenna signal: -44dBm
    Antenna noise: -100dBm
    Signal Quality: 100
    Antenna: 0
    dB antenna signal: 56dB
802.11 radio information
    PHY type: 802.11b (4)
    Short preamble: False
    Data rate: 1.0 Mb/s
    Channel: 1
    Frequency: 2412MHz
    Signal strength (dBm): -44dBm
    Noise level (dBm): -100dBm
    [Duration: 1712µs]
IEEE 802.11 Association Request, Flags: ........C
    Type/Subtype: Association Request (0x0000)
    Frame Control Field: 0x0000
        .... ..00 = Version: 0
        .... 00.. = Type: Management frame (0)
        0000 .... = Subtype: 0
        Flags: 0x00
    .000 0001 0011 1010 = Duration: 314 microseconds
    Receiver address: Sagemcom_fb:5d:9d (00:78:9e:fb:5d:9d)
    Destination address: Sagemcom_fb:5d:9d (00:78:9e:fb:5d:9d)
    Transmitter address: SamsungE_74:b9:f9 (d0:22:be:74:b9:f9)
    Source address: SamsungE_74:b9:f9 (d0:22:be:74:b9:f9)
    BSS Id: Sagemcom_fb:5d:9d (00:78:9e:fb:5d:9d)
    .... .... .... 0000 = Fragment number: 0
    0011 0011 1000 .... = Sequence number: 824
    Frame check sequence: 0xa7de824d [correct]
    [FCS Status: Good]
IEEE 802.11 wireless LAN
    Fixed parameters (4 bytes)
        Capabilities Information: 0x0431
            .... .... .... ...1 = ESS capabilities: Transmitter is an AP
            .... .... .... ..0. = IBSS status: Transmitter belongs to a BSS
            .... ..0. .... 00.. = CFP participation capabilities: No point coordinator at AP (0x00)
            .... .... ...1 .... = Privacy: AP/STA can support WEP
            .... .... ..1. .... = Short Preamble: Allowed
            .... .... .0.. .... = PBCC: Not Allowed
            .... .... 0... .... = Channel Agility: Not in use
            .... ...0 .... .... = Spectrum Management: Not Implemented
            .... .1.. .... .... = Short Slot Time: In use
            .... 0... .... .... = Automatic Power Save Delivery: Not Implemented
            ...0 .... .... .... = Radio Measurement: Not Implemented
            ..0. .... .... .... = DSSS-OFDM: Not Allowed
            .0.. .... .... .... = Delayed Block Ack: Not Implemented
            0... .... .... .... = Immediate Block Ack: Not Implemented
        Listen Interval: 0x000a
    Tagged parameters (158 bytes)
        Tag: SSID parameter set: HOTBOX-9810
            Tag Number: SSID parameter set (0)
            Tag length: 11
            SSID: HOTBOX-9810
        Tag: Supported Rates 1(B), 2(B), 5.5(B), 11(B), 18, 24, 36, 54, [Mbit/sec]
            Tag Number: Supported Rates (1)
            Tag length: 8
            Supported Rates: 1(B) (0x82)
            Supported Rates: 2(B) (0x84)
            Supported Rates: 5.5(B) (0x8b)
            Supported Rates: 11(B) (0x96)
            Supported Rates: 18 (0x24)
            Supported Rates: 24 (0x30)
            Supported Rates: 36 (0x48)
            Supported Rates: 54 (0x6c)
        Tag: Power Capability Min: 8, Max: 18
            Tag Number: Power Capability (33)
            Tag length: 2
            Minimum Transmit Power: 8
            Maximum Transmit Power: 18
        Tag: Supported Channels
            Tag Number: Supported Channels (36)
            Tag length: 2
            Supported Channels Set #1 First: 1, Range: 13 
        Tag: RSN Information
            Tag Number: RSN Information (48)
            Tag length: 20
            RSN Version: 1
            Group Cipher Suite: 00:0f:ac (Ieee 802.11) TKIP
            Pairwise Cipher Suite Count: 1
            Pairwise Cipher Suite List 00:0f:ac (Ieee 802.11) AES (CCM)
            Auth Key Management (AKM) Suite Count: 1
            Auth Key Management (AKM) List 00:0f:ac (Ieee 802.11) PSK
            RSN Capabilities: 0x0000
        Tag: Extended Supported Rates 6, 9, 12, 48, [Mbit/sec]
            Tag Number: Extended Supported Rates (50)
            Tag length: 4
            Extended Supported Rates: 6 (0x0c)
            Extended Supported Rates: 9 (0x12)
            Extended Supported Rates: 12 (0x18)
            Extended Supported Rates: 48 (0x60)
        Tag: HT Capabilities (802.11n D1.10)
            Tag Number: HT Capabilities (802.11n D1.10) (45)
            Tag length: 26
            HT Capabilities Info: 0x112d
                .... .... .... ...1 = HT LDPC coding capability: Transmitter supports receiving LDPC coded packets
                .... .... .... ..0. = HT Support channel width: Transmitter only supports 20MHz operation
                .... .... .... 11.. = HT SM Power Save: SM Power Save disabled (0x3)
                .... .... ...0 .... = HT Green Field: Transmitter is not able to receive PPDUs with Green Field (GF) preamble
                .... .... ..1. .... = HT Short GI for 20MHz: Supported
                .... .... .0.. .... = HT Short GI for 40MHz: Not supported
                .... .... 0... .... = HT Tx STBC: Not supported
                .... ..01 .... .... = HT Rx STBC: Rx support of one spatial stream (0x1)
                .... .0.. .... .... = HT Delayed Block ACK: Transmitter does not support HT-Delayed BlockAck
                .... 0... .... .... = HT Max A-MSDU length: 3839 bytes
                ...1 .... .... .... = HT DSSS/CCK mode in 40MHz: Will/Can use DSSS/CCK in 40 MHz
                ..0. .... .... .... = HT PSMP Support: Won't/Can't support PSMP operation
                .0.. .... .... .... = HT Forty MHz Intolerant: Use of 40 MHz transmissions unrestricted/allowed
                0... .... .... .... = HT L-SIG TXOP Protection support: Not supported
            A-MPDU Parameters: 0x17
            Rx Supported Modulation and Coding Scheme Set: MCS Set
            HT Extended Capabilities: 0x0000
            Transmit Beam Forming (TxBF) Capabilities: 0x00000000
            Antenna Selection (ASEL) Capabilities: 0x00
        Tag: Vendor Specific: Broadcom
            Tag Number: Vendor Specific (221)
            Tag length: 9
            OUI: 00:10:18 (Broadcom)
            Vendor Specific OUI Type: 2
            Vendor Specific Data: 020000100000
        Tag: Vendor Specific: Epigram, Inc.: HT Capabilities (802.11n D1.10)
            Tag Number: Vendor Specific (221)
            Tag length: 30
            OUI: 00:90:4c (Epigram, Inc.)
            Vendor Specific OUI Type: 51
            802.11n (Pre) Type: HT Capabilities (802.11n D1.10) (51)
            HT Capabilities Info (VS): 0x112d
                .... .... .... ...1 = HT LDPC coding capability: Transmitter supports receiving LDPC coded packets
                .... .... .... ..0. = HT Support channel width: Transmitter only supports 20MHz operation
                .... .... .... 11.. = HT SM Power Save: SM Power Save disabled (0x3)
                .... .... ...0 .... = HT Green Field: Transmitter is not able to receive PPDUs with Green Field (GF) preamble
                .... .... ..1. .... = HT Short GI for 20MHz: Supported
                .... .... .0.. .... = HT Short GI for 40MHz: Not supported
                .... .... 0... .... = HT Tx STBC: Not supported
                .... ..01 .... .... = HT Rx STBC: Rx support of one spatial stream (0x1)
                .... .0.. .... .... = HT Delayed Block ACK: Transmitter does not support HT-Delayed BlockAck
                .... 0... .... .... = HT Max A-MSDU length: 3839 bytes
                ...1 .... .... .... = HT DSSS/CCK mode in 40MHz: Will/Can use DSSS/CCK in 40 MHz
                ..0. .... .... .... = HT PSMP Support: Won't/Can't support PSMP operation
                .0.. .... .... .... = HT Forty MHz Intolerant: Use of 40 MHz transmissions unrestricted/allowed
                0... .... .... .... = HT L-SIG TXOP Protection support: Not supported
            A-MPDU Parameters (VS): 0x17
            Rx Supported Modulation and Coding Scheme Set (VS): MCS Set
            HT Extended Capabilities (VS): 0x0000
            Transmit Beam Forming (TxBF) Capabilities (VS): 0x00000000
            Antenna Selection (ASEL) Capabilities (VS): 0x00
        Tag: Vendor Specific: Microsoft Corp.: WMM/WME: Information Element
            Tag Number: Vendor Specific (221)
            Tag length: 7
            OUI: 00:50:f2 (Microsoft Corp.)
            Vendor Specific OUI Type: 2
            Type: WMM/WME (0x02)
            WME Subtype: Information Element (0)
            WME Version: 1
            WME QoS Info: 0x00
        Tag: Vendor Specific: Epigram, Inc.
            Tag Number: Vendor Specific (221)
            Tag length: 17
            OUI: 00:90:4c (Epigram, Inc.)
            Vendor Specific OUI Type: 55
            802.11n (Pre) Type: Unknown (55)
            802.11n (Pre) Unknown Data: 00000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probe response frame contains a lot of information about the encryption used by the AP.

First of all the **vendor specific WPA Information Element** tells you that the AP is using WPA2 with a pre-shared key (PSK).

Furthermore, the **Robust Security Network (RSN) Element** gives you further details about the cipher suites used. Some more details can be found in this [post](https://community.cisco.com/t5/wireless-mobility-documents/802-11-sniffer-capture-analysis-wpa-wpa2-with-psk-or-eap/ta-p/3116990).

Regarding the exchange of the password. There you need to look for the **EAPOL frames** in your capture. In those four frames, the [four way handshake for WPA2](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17782/164974) is performed, where not the password, but a message integrity check (MIC) element is sent from station to AP. This MIC proves that the station has the correct pairwise master key (PMK),  which is used for encryption. This pairwise master key is derived from the pre-shared key in WPA2-PSK.

Comment: Just to be clear, how did you know it's WPA2? where the packet specifically states WPA version 1?

Comment: You can implicitely tell from the RSN, which contains the AES (CCM) protocol, which was introduced for WPA2, whereas WPA was using only TKIP. The information element actually states WPA version: 1, but this does not refer to whether it is WPA or WPA2.

Answer (score 3):

Association req/response is where client <-> AP determine whether the client station meets requirements for the WiFI association (e.g supported encryption type)

Once the 802.11 state machine is complete via probing/open auth/association then it moves onto PSK(pre-shared-key)/802.1x security processing which at this point if you check frames should have further information about challenge texts etc used for authentication.

Once all of that is complete then frames can be bridged between client station and the AP.